# SharePoint solution is stuck on deploying (Scheduled at ..)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2019

In my SharePoint 2019 dev, I tried to update a solution, however it is stuck on: "deploying (scheduled at ...)".

```
I have done the following to solve the issue:
- restarted server
- restarted Timer service in Services and in SharePoint
- ran IISRESET
- ran the following: stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs
- restarted server again
- checked the uls logs, but nothing supsicious
```

but still no solution. Any help please?

**Edit**:
I see in the logs the following:

```
Database with Id 5d33b7d5-bd85-5847-2251-e15bc1242f2a was not found in database collection. Returning null.     Timer Job webhook-processing
```

How can I figure out which database was that?

Comment: If you have access to DB server then you can try this SQL syntax "SELECT DB_NAME(5d33b7d5-bd85-5847-2251-e15bc1242f2a) AS [Database Name];"

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '<Guid>' to data type int.

Comment: Kindly give a try to this - SELECT * FROM sys.databases where service_broker_guid='{GUID}'